# Attempt to invoke interface method 'void org.osmdroid.api.IMapController.animateTo(org.osmdroid.api.IGeoPoint)'

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I just finished working on the map using osm but I have an error like this

I have searched for a solution on the internet but I did not find it

this is the code for setupMap

```
        // setting tile map
        BingMapTileSource.setBingKey(getString(R.string.bingkey));
        BingMapTileSource bingMap = new BingMapTileSource(null);
        bingMap.setStyle(BingMapTileSource.IMAGERYSET_ROAD);


        // menambah overlay ke dalam map
        mapView.getOverlays().add(rotationGestureOverlay);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(compassOverlay);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationNewOverlay);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(roadNodeMarkers);

        //setting mapView
        mapView.setTileSource(bingMap);
        mapView.setTilesScaledToDpi(true);
        mapView.setMinZoomLevel(1.0);
        mapView.setMaxZoomLevel(21.0);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);
        mapView.getZoomController().setVisibility(CustomZoomButtonsController.Visibility.NEVER);

        mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint(-5.402213, 105.264093));
    }
```

and i got error like this

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void org.osmdroid.api.IMapController.animateTo(org.osmdroid.api.IGeoPoint)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.donordarahanjeng.directmap.setupMap(directmap.java:449)
        at com.example.donordarahanjeng.directmap.onCreate(directmap.java:150)
```

when i click error he will head to `mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint(-5.402213, 105.264093));`

and this is my full code

```
public class directmap extends AppCompatActivity implements  MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener
        , PermissionsListener, View.OnClickListener, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
//, MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener, PermissionsListener, View.OnClickListener {

    @BindView(R.id.mapViewosm)
    MapView mapView;

    @BindView(R.id.route)
    FloatingActionButton route;
    //private MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient locationProviderClient;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private LocationComponent locationComponent;
    // variables for calculating and drawing a route
    private DirectionsRoute currentRoute;
    private static final String TAG = "DirectionsActivity";
    private NavigationMapRoute navigationMapRoute;
    private RoadManager roadManager;
    private MyLocationNewOverlay myLocationNewOverlay;
    private LocationManager manager;

    private IMapController mapController;
    private RotationGestureOverlay rotationGestureOverlay;
    private GpsMyLocationProvider myLocationProvider;
    private CompassOverlay compassOverlay;
    protected FolderOverlay roadNodeMarkers;
    //private MyLocationNewOverlay myLocationNewOverlay;

    private GeoPoint startPoint, destPoint;
    private Bitmap startIcon;

   // private LocationHelper locationHelper;
    private Location location;

    private double lat, lng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(context, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context));
        //Mapbox.getInstance(directmap.this, getString(R.string.access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_directmap);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
       // mapView = (MapView) findViewById (R.id.mapViewosm);
       // button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);


        roadManager = new GraphHopperRoadManager(getString(R.string.apikey), true);
        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        route.setOnClickListener(this);
        //mapView.onCre(savedInstanceState);
        //mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        startIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_mark);
        //ambil lokasi pendonatur
        lat = -5.402213; //getIntent().getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0);,
        lng = 105.264113;//getIntent().getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0);

        setupMap();
        setupOverlay();
        addMarker();
    }

    private void addMarker() {
        Marker destMarker = new Marker(mapView);

        destPoint = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
        destMarker.setPosition(destPoint);
        destMarker.setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));
        destMarker.setSubDescription(getIntent().getStringExtra("username"));
        destMarker.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mark));

        mapView.getOverlays().add(destMarker);
        mapView.invalidate();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //mapView.onStop();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        //mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
       // mapView.onLowMemory();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       /* if (v == button) {
            boolean simulateRoute = true;
            NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                    .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                    .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
                    .build();
            // Call this method with Context from within an Activity
            NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(directmap.this, options);

            startPoint = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            GeoPoint destination = destPoint;
            ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<>();
            waypoints.add(startPoint);
            waypoints.add(destination);

            // algoritma astar
            roadManager.addRequestOption("algorithm=astarbi");

            Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);

        } */
       if (v.getId() == R.id.route) {
           getRoute2();
       }
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getRoute2() {

        startPoint = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        GeoPoint destination = destPoint;
        ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<>();
        waypoints.add(startPoint);
        waypoints.add(destination);

        // algoritma astar
        roadManager.addRequestOption("algorithm=astarbi");

        Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);

        // build rute overlay
        Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road);
        //mengatur warna dan lebar rute
        roadOverlay.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        roadOverlay.setWidth(7);

        putRoadNodes(road);

        mapView.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
        mapView.invalidate();
    }

    private void setupOverlay() {

        //setting map controller
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(13.0);

        //setting node marker
        roadNodeMarkers = new FolderOverlay();
        roadNodeMarkers.setName("Route Steps");

        // setting compass
        compassOverlay = new CompassOverlay(directmap.this
                , new InternalCompassOrientationProvider(directmap.this), mapView);
        compassOverlay.enableCompass();
        compassOverlay.setPointerMode(true);

        //setting provider lokasi
        myLocationProvider = new GpsMyLocationProvider(this.getBaseContext());
        myLocationProvider.setLocationUpdateMinTime(1000);
        myLocationProvider.setLocationUpdateMinDistance(50);

        //setting gesture rotasi
        rotationGestureOverlay = new RotationGestureOverlay(mapView);
        rotationGestureOverlay.setEnabled(true);

        //setting location overlay
        myLocationNewOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(myLocationProvider, mapView);
        myLocationNewOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        myLocationNewOverlay.enableFollowLocation();
        myLocationNewOverlay.setPersonIcon(startIcon);

    }

    private void setupMap() {
        // setting tile map
        BingMapTileSource.setBingKey(getString(R.string.bingkey));
        BingMapTileSource bingMap = new BingMapTileSource(null);
        bingMap.setStyle(BingMapTileSource.IMAGERYSET_ROAD);


        // menambah overlay ke dalam map
        mapView.getOverlays().add(rotationGestureOverlay);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(compassOverlay);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationNewOverlay);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(roadNodeMarkers);

        //setting mapView
        mapView.setTileSource(bingMap);
        mapView.setTilesScaledToDpi(true);
        mapView.setMinZoomLevel(1.0);
        mapView.setMaxZoomLevel(21.0);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);
        mapView.getZoomController().setVisibility(CustomZoomButtonsController.Visibility.NEVER);

        mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint(-5.402213, 105.264093));
    }


    private void putRoadNodes(Road road) {
        roadNodeMarkers.getItems().clear();
        Drawable nodeIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mark); //marker node

        int n = road.mNodes.size();

        MarkerInfoWindow infoWindow = new MarkerInfoWindow(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble, mapView);
        TypedArray iconIds = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.direction);
        //ambil titik node
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            RoadNode node = road.mNodes.get(i);
            String instructions = (node.mInstructions == null ? "" : node.mInstructions);
            Marker nodeMarker = new Marker(mapView);
            nodeMarker.setTitle("Step " + (i + 1));
            nodeMarker.setSnippet(instructions);
            nodeMarker.setSubDescription(Road.getLengthDurationText(this, node.mLength, node.mDuration));
            nodeMarker.setPosition(node.mLocation);
            nodeMarker.setIcon(nodeIcon);
            nodeMarker.setInfoWindow(infoWindow);
            int iconId = iconIds.getResourceId(node.mManeuverType, R.drawable.ic_empty); //icempty
            if (iconId != R.drawable.ic_empty) //icempty
            {
                Drawable image = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), iconId, null);
                nodeMarker.setImage(image);
            }
            nodeMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER);
            roadNodeMarkers.add(nodeMarker);
        }

        iconIds.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

What should I do? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your order of initialization is wrong. `mapController` isn't initialized yet.

`mapController` gets initialized in `setupOverlay()`:

```
private void setupOverlay() {

    //setting map controller
    mapController = mapView.getController();
```

You are calling `mapController.animateTo()` from within `setupMap()`. However `setupMap()` is called *before* `setupOverlay()`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    [...]

    setupMap();
    setupOverlay();
```

Either call `setupOverlay()` before `setupMap()` or initialize `mapController` at an earlier step.

Comment: thanks you sir! it's working, but i have something problem now, my map only show grid, whats problem?

Comment: I'm not sure. Take a minimal osmdroid example and compare it against your code.